# Is there any Javascript Chart Library which i can use for Blackberry browser. Without ActiveX?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Is there any Javascript Chart Library which i can use for Blackberry browser. Without ActiveX?

I want to make one blackberry browser based chart report app using PhoneGap with html and javascript.

Thanks
--Raghav

Comment: Did you find a solution to add to the broser field???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) / [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)
- [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Both Google charts and RaphaelJS use SVG (which in turn renders using VML in IE). gRaphael unfortunately hasn't been maintained in the past year, but there are several examples that show various charts.

Comment: Google Charts is a good suggestion, but I wonder why you tell it uses SVG? It uses PNG.

Comment: Because there's both SVG charts and the original [image charts api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/).